# This expression has type 'a list -> 'a list but an expression was expected of type int

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec first_part n l =
  if n = 0  then
    []
  else
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | x :: xs -> x :: first_part n-1 xs

let rec second_part n l =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs ->
      if n = 0 then l 
      else second_part n-1 xs

let rec split n l =
  match n with
  | 0-> ([], l)
  | n -> (first_part n l , second_part n l)
```

Comment: So what is the function supposed to do?

Comment: Not a solution, but a suggestion. `first_part` could be expressed as a single match. `let rec first_part n l = match n, l with 0, _ | _, [] -> [] | _, x::xs -> x :: first_part n-1 xs`. For fixes see [Jeffrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71841621/15261315).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a very well posed question. You don't show the details of the error or ask a specific question. You also didn't format the code in a readable way (I improved it for you).

Your problem is that

```
first_part n-1 xs
```

is parsed like this

```
(first_part n) - (1 xs)
```

Function calls in OCaml (juxtaposed expressions) have high precedence. So you need parentheses around `(n - 1)` in two places.